# How can I get string address from tx.sender in RIDE?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm writing a smart contract using RIDE and I need to get sender address as string, is it possible in RIDE to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.
you can get the string address as following:

```
let senderAddress = addressFromPublicKey(tx.senderPublicKey)
```

Or

```
let senderAddress= toBase58String(addressFromPublicKey(tx.senderPublicKey).bytes)
```